# Error Creating window handle

Tags: c#, winforms

I've written a client-server c# app and let it run all night , and when i wanted to see if it was still working i've found an error on the server . unfortunately the app is to big to paste in some code, but i get an error at

> Application.Run(form1)

in the program.cs that says [image]

The first two messageboxes can be ignored (from left to right ) because they are supposed to show , but the other

> delegate buton couldn't be executed

comes from this code ánd mai have a part in this error(this code is in form1.cs) :

```
public void setButonState(inout_buton b, bool t, int q,int contor)
        {
            try
            {
                if (b.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    Callback d = new Callback(setButonState);
                    this.Invoke(d, new object[] { b, t, q, contor });
                }
                else
                {
                    b.Enabled = t;
                    if (q == 0) b.setBackgroundGrey();
                    if (q == 1) b.setBackgroundGreen();
                    if (q == 2) b.setBackgroundRed();
                    if (q == 3) b.setBackgroundOrange();

                    b.setSecondaryLabel(contor);

                }
            }
            catch { new ShowMessageBox("FORM1 : delegate buton couldn't be executed"); }

        }
```

My question is : in what conditions does these errors show ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Diagnose this with Taskmgr.exe, Processes tab.  View + Select Columns and tick USER objects.  Observe this value for your process while it runs.  It should be steadily climbing.  When it reaches 10,000 then your program will bomb with this exception.

This is caused by not calling Dispose() on controls that you remove from the Controls collection yourself, either by calling Remove() or Clear().

Comment: so if i would use Dispose() it will work ? and how can i extend this 10000 limit ?

Comment: Fix the bug in your code, don't look for a workaround that will crash your program later.  Ten thousand windows is an insanely large number of windows.  A couple of dozen is normal.  The USER objects counter is an excellent diagnostic.

Comment: if i call periodicaly GC.Collect() , will this help ?

Comment: The thing is that i have only one window and as some information come there apear pop-ups but not in big numbers

Comment: No, this won't fix the problem.  It's a quirk of Winforms, removing a Control from the Controls collection or setting its Parent property to null (same thing) gets it hosted in the so-called 'parking window'.  Which allows the window to stay alive when you move it from one container to another.  If you don't actually move it somewhere else then it stays referenced by that parking window.  A permanent leak.

Comment: i've looked now and it seems that the user objects stay quite stable around 200 .. any other possible leaks ?

Comment: and another thing , those this apply also to user controls ?

Comment: I can't help you guess at getting a repro.  You are using threading, that's always a source of random behavior.  Lock your workstation or get the screen saver to run, that's always a good way to induce problems caused by SystemEvents initialization.  User controls are no different.

Comment: I think you were right about the 10000 user object limit . The thing is that the server is remote and at night the temperature(which my client recieves through a micro-controller and sends to the server) is between 22 and 22.5 . At 22 it inserts some packages , thing that happens a lot ! Anyway thanks for the 10000-u-objects limit tip !

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like your application is trying to access protected data.  Keep in mind, when your system locks due to inactivity/logging off, your application will not be able to interact with certain aspects of the system.  Such an example would be trying to grab the handle of a window or take a screen shot.  These will both throw errors.

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving this same error when calling a static classes method from within a foreach statement.  The User Objects count continued to increase and was not released until the program ended or the error occurred.

I changed the static method into an instance method and the User Object stayed at 60.

```
//created and instance of the object
var oIP = new ImportProvider();

foreach(var patient in lstPatients)
{
    var oP = PatientConversionProvider.GetPatient(oPatient.RecordId);

    if(oP != null)
    {

        //referenced the instance member (changed from a static member)
        if(oIP.ImportDataIntoSmartRx(oP))
        {
            successCount++;
            lstMrNumber.Add(oPatient.MrNumber);
        }

        totalCount++;
```

...